# Cómo insertar datos en tiempo real de otra página en la mía

Tags: javascript, html, web

no encuentro por ninguna lado lo que quiero realizar, y es que quiero hacer una página similar a esta: [rulopro.com](https://rulopro.com) lo que hace esta página es hacer operaciones matemáticas con números reales de otras páginas como cotización del dolar, compra y venta, etc, lo que quiero hacer o saber cómo se hace eso, poner datos en tiempo reales en mí página y con esos datos reales hacer operaciones matemáticas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obtener datos en tiempo real de una pagina a la tuya ?

Necesitas:

- Aprender a utilizar una API externa, la vas a manejar por javascript para mostrar/insertar sus datos en tu pagina, utilizando ***AJAX***, ***fetch*** , o si quieres una librería ***jquery*** (con los comandos de ajax). es una forma muy utilizada y vas a tener que aprender a recibir JSON (javascript object notation) la notación de objetos que maneja javascript para reconocer que necesitas meter en donde.
- Otra forma es utilizando un Web Service de algún otro sitio web, que tiene 2 formas de recibir información **SOAP**(xml) y **REST**(json).

No puedo mostrarte código ahora mismo, pero buscando sobre dichos temas encontraras rápido la forma de hacerlo funcionar.